# Radscheduler adding a class to a specific date

Tags: telerik, radscheduler

I have a telerik Radscheduler and want to give specific days a different background color. I prefer to give the whole column a different class for the specific date, but only the date header row would also be good.

Searched the internet, but could only find changing appointment background colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution on the telerik-forum:

An easy and convenient way of achieving such functionality would be using the RadScheduler TimeSlotCreated server-side event and apply a css class to all time slot objects associated with a specific date as shown in the code snippet below:

Markup code:

```
<telerik:RadScheduler runat="server" ID="RadScheduler1" OnTimeSlotCreated="RadScheduler1_TimeSlotCreated"></telerik:RadScheduler>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void RadScheduler1_TimeSlotCreated(object sender, TimeSlotCreatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadScheduler1.SelectedView == SchedulerViewType.WeekView)
        {
            if (e.TimeSlot.Start.Date.Day == 23 )
            {
                e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "red";
            }
        }
    }
```

css code:

```
<style type="text/css">
       html .RadScheduler .red {
           background: red;
       }
   </style>
```

Special thanks to Boyan Dimitrov of Telerik